# Maintenance wise, is `else while` without intervening braces considered safe?

Tags: coding-style, language-agnostic, maintainability

Is `else while` without intervening braces considered "safe" maintenance wise?

Writing `if-else` code without braces like below...

```
if (blah)
    foo();
else
    bar();
```

...carries a risk because the lack of braces make it very easy to change the meaning of the code inadvertently.

However, is below also risky?

```
if (blah)
{
    ...
}
else while (!bloop())
{
    bar();
}
```

Or is `else while` without intervening braces considered "safe"?

Comment: to me `else while` looks icky. I'd use `else { while (condition) { ... } }`.

Comment: I think it is too subjective for a proper answer ... I mzself wouldn't do it as I won't expect a loop there, and thinks I don't expect make readability hard.

Comment: I would [extract method](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) for while-stuff

Comment: I think it's quite obvious that it is a very bad idea! Don't ever do that for the sake of the mental integrity of your co-workers.

Comment: Honestly, it gives me the creeps. `if` is only evaluated once, but `while` denotes a loop, so connecting both gives me a unsubstantiated feeling that the `if` is part of the loop... somehow...

Comment: I'm always a little surprised by what people on this forum consider 'hard'. Code where `else while` contributes to the difficulty of a particular code piece must be so trivial that it can easily be skimmed anyway. 'harder' code cannot be skimmed anyway, and come on guys, it's not even hard to parse, *especially* with keyword highlighting. I'd even consider it *more* readable since the nesting is more obvious.

Comment: And what if in the `else` clause you want to do the `while` **and** do something more? Just use braces, please.

Comment: edit has done in Rev 2 to **give less chances for misreaders to turn a good question into easier-to-read garbage voting game**. Voted to re-open

Comment: @Max:  I don't want little "gotcha"s in my code.  The blocks are in a parallel position, but they aren't parallel.  I skim code largely to get context, and the fact that a construct is fairly easy to parse if I take a careful look at it is largely irrelevant.

Comment: `else while` is the solution to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: On matters like this, I go with "if you have to ask, it's probably best to avoid"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That reminds me this code:

```
if ( ... ) try {
..
} catch (Exception e) {
..
} else {
...
}
```

Every time you are combining two types of blocks, forgetting braces and not increasing indentation, you are creating code very difficult to understand and maintain.

Comment: Good example. What a horrible way to write it.

Comment: Wow, this answer is ridiculously convincing!

Comment: You can easily set up modern IDEs to automatically format code on saving - including inserting braces and correcting the indentation. So this is only half an argument. Properly indented this would pose no problem for readability, whether there are braces or not.

Answer (score 55):

Perhaps it is because I learnt my trade (way back when) using the [Jackson Entity Structure Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_system_development#Designing_the_diagrams) method, but I subscribe to the view that the only *correct* unbraced term after an `if` or an `else` is a subsequent `if` (ie allowing an `else if` ladder)

Anything else (no pun intended) leaves potential for misunderstanding and/or maintenance issues. That is the central aspect of the OPs idea being "unsafe".

I'd also be very cagey about including the `while()` on the same line as the `else` - whether braced or not.  It doesn't read right to me... the lack of any extra indentation masks that it is the `else` clause. And lack of clarity makes for misunderstandings (see above).

So in the example I would strongly advise/recommend (and insist, in my team) on:

```
if ( blah )
{
    ...
}
else
{
    while ( !bloop() )
    {
        bar();
    }
}
```

Of course, I would also expect to see suitable comments too.

-- Edit --

Recently Apple suffered from an SSL vulnerability, caused by a poor maintenance fix - that added a second line to an un-braced single line.  So let's put to bed the idea that unbraced single lines are OK?

Comment: I agree on if being the only correct term to follow an else. If there was an `else while` I would probably not even notice there was a loop in a quick skimming of the code, especially if the condition I was looking for was satisfied by the if.

Comment: It's funny. Everyone says that it's easier to read if everything is in braces. I find the opposite to be true. If it's only one statement, keeping it out of braces makes it easier to read. Less clutter. It may only be because I have always done it that way.

Comment: @JeffDavis that's a good catch. "Easier to read" is a typical invitation to useless holy war. I for one prefer braces, but not because of irrelevant "easiertoread" garbage (to me for example it's exactly the opposite) but because it's harder to break in further code maintenance. By the way OP spelled it better in their question: _is `else while` without intervening braces **considered "safe"**?_

Comment: @JeffDavis - I know this thread is two years old, but Apple recently discovered why not using braces is not a good idea http://andrewbanks.com/could-misra-c-have-prevented-the-apple-iphone-ssl-bug/

Comment: @Andrew By the way, Apple's Swift language now explicitly forbids one-line flow control. That bug could be one of the reasons to do so.

Answer (score 6):

I have always been taught to keep everything in braces, indented and commented. I believe it's much easier to read and spot errors. Personally i feel modularity is key so i would always write the code like this :

```
    if(blah)
    {
     ....
    }
    else
    {
       while(!bloop()
       {
        bar;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I would **extract method** and make it

```
if ( blah )
{
    ...
}
else
{
   newMethod();
}
```

---

See "extract method" approach explained at [Refactoring Catalog](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) site:

> *You have a code fragment that can be grouped together.*
>
> **Turn the fragment into a method whose name explains the purpose of the method.**
>
> ```
> void printOwing() {
>     printBanner();
>
>     //print details
>     System.out.println ("name:    " + _name);
>     System.out.println ("amount    " + getOutstanding());
> }
> ```
>
> [image: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/arrow.gif]
>
> ```
> void printOwing() {
>     printBanner();
>     printDetails(getOutstanding());
> }
>
> void printDetails (double outstanding) {
>     System.out.println ("name:    " + _name);
>     System.out.println ("amount    " + outstanding);
> }
> ```

Comment: Depends... if for example, the while loop used function level data, you're now having to more that data to module (or class, if using C++) level. And if only a small snippet of code, you're into trivial methods.  But sometimes, depending on circumstances, I'd agree.

Comment: +1 Smart C++ compilers can inline a function. In .Net environment small functions are better due to JIT.

Answer (score 4):

It might be fine if it stays simple like that although personally I don't like it and my preference is to use braces even for the simplest if/else code blocks. It's just tidier for me.

However, where this gets messy is when you have nested if/else loops some with braces some without. A While loop in the middle of all that spaghetti! I've worked with code that bad and it's a nightmare to debug and to understand. This follows on from the first point it's fine when it stays simple and you're happy with it, but then other programmers come along and add things to it, probably an if else within the while loop. If it's written clean in the first place then there's less chance of this happening.

The point is to make stuff clear so that other programmers can see at a glance what's right and wrong. Write code so that the pattern looks right and doesn't jar.

The flip side of this is that maybe I could see some people claiming that in certain instances this reads well. If I've got the resource I need do this processing else while I'm waiting for something do this.  Even then to me there's still no difference in nesting the while loop inside the else block.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider it as a bad habit of coding. Sometimes it works perfectly fine and you will have no problem in compiling and running the code. At other times it may cause serious bugs and you will end up spending hours in fixing that bug.

It is always recommended to modularize your code. If you have to put a while loop in else part put it in a block so that others, when working on your code can easily understand the logic.

```
if ( blah )
{
    ...
}
else
{
    while ( !bloop() )
    {
        bar();
    }
}
```

It's a good practice to put code in blocks. It makes it simpler and easier to understand and debug as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, despite everyone argues about using braces and seem to love them, I actually prefer the opposite. I only use braces when I have to because I find it more readable and concise without.

```
if (...)
   foo();
else while(...)
   bar();
```

...I actually find this "`else while(...)`" remarkably readable! It even reads like plain English! But I guess people will all find it strange because it's unusual to say the least.

In the end, we all tend to make it idiot-proof with braces though ...because, well, you know.

Comment: that'll be especially readable after some innocent maintainer changes `else while(...) bar();` to something like `else while(...) foobar(); bar();` :)

Comment: well, I would say that is a *pretty stupid and dangerous* innocent maintainer. I know the principle of dumbing it down to avoid stupid errors ...but going so far is nevertheless fairly sad. But I knew I'd get such comments and downvotes. No problem.

Comment: "Always code as if the person who will maintain your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live." ([Alan Braggins](http://neil.franklin.ch/Usenet/alt.folklore.computers/19980115_Paranoia_in_Programming "quote source: alt.folklore.computers"))

Comment: Well, everything boils down to what you assume the stupidest level of someone working on your code would be. I argue that if your "maintainer" gets confuser by these four lines of code ...then you have a massive problem at hands. And if it's a violent psycho, you have two. ;)

Comment: *if* - well the link I refer in above, has _expanded_ version of this quote: _Programmer 1: 'There's a nice quote here - "Always code as if the person who will maintain your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live"'. Programmer 2: (Looks over at maintainer) 'What do you mean "as if"?'_

Answer (score 3):

What is so wrong with braces that so many people is trying to avoid writing them ?

What problem does exactly `else while` solve ?

Braces are cheap and good, and they make code intention evident and plain as opposed to clever and witty.

Quoting Unix Philosophy:

### Rule of Clarity: Clarity is better than cleverness.

> Because maintenance is so important and so expensive, write programs
>   as if the most important communication they do is not to the computer
>   that executes them but to the human beings who will read and maintain
>   the source code in the future (including yourself).

Answer (score 2):

I always put braces, just because you might add another line when in hurry, indent it, forget the braces and scratch your head what's happening. I keep the opening bracket on the same line, but it doesn't matter. I both cases it's better to have them.

```
if(blah) {
    foo();
}
else {
    bar();
}
```

Comment: Positioning of braces probably triggers more argument than anything beyond (or possibly including) religion!

Comment: Agreed. Will edit my answer to emphasize on their existence, not position.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with

```
if (blah)
    foo();
else
    bar();
```

just like there's nothing wrong with

```
if (blah) foo(); else bar();
```

in the right circumstances (your circumstances may vary, but that particular style is best used when you have a lot of repetitive code - then the view of each line is more important than the stylistic indentation)

But if you choose one way, keep to it - consistency is king. So your second example is very bad, as the if expression had brackets for its statement, the while statement should be inside the brackets for the else clause, not outside it.

---

besides, I have seen this code before:

```
if (x) foo()
{
  bar();
}
```

and it was written by the coding standard nazi himself (who insisted on brackets for everything).

Answer (score 1):

Modern IDEs can easily be configured to reformat (including removing or adding unnecessary braces) and/or reindent the code on saving a file. Thus your example would automatically look like for instance

```
if (blah) {
  blub();
} else
  while (!bloop()) {
    bar();
  }
```

The indentation always makes the nesting easily visible, even without unneccesary braces. So, if you manage to enforce such IDE settings, I see no risk.

Personally, I find code that omits the braces and linebreaks much more readable since it avoids clutter:

```
if (blah) blub();
else while (!bloop()) bar();
```

But of course, many developers are very happy to argue about such things forever and a day.